# Pandas datetime conversion failing to produce monotonically increasing UTC time, any ideas why?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion, timezone

from my data I have a bunch of timedata:

```
    time = pd.Series(['2015-03-08 01:00:00',
                  '2015-03-08 01:30:00',
                  '2015-03-08 02:00:00',
                  '2015-03-08 02:30:00',
                  '2015-03-08 03:00:00',
                  '2015-03-08 02:00:00',
                  '2015-03-08 02:30:00',
                  '2015-03-08 03:00:00',
                  '2015-03-08 03:30:00',
                  '2015-11-01 00:30:00',
                  '2015-11-01 01:00:00',
                  '2015-11-01 01:30:00',
                  '2015-11-01 02:00:00',
                  '2015-11-01 02:30:00',
                  '2015-11-01 01:00:00',
                  '2015-11-01 01:30:00',
                  '2015-11-01 02:00:00',
                  '2015-11-01 02:30:00',
                  '2015-11-01 03:00:00',
                  '2015-11-01 03:30:00'])
```

I want to convert this to UTC using `local.dt.tz_convert('UTC')`, after applying an offset:
`offset = pd.Series([-7, -7, -7, -7, -7, -6, -6, -6, -6, -6, -6, -6, -6, -6,  -7, -7, -7, -7, -7, -7])`

and using

```
offset = offset.replace({-7:'-07:00', -6:'-06:00'})
local =  (pd.to_datetime(time)
    .groupby(offset)
    .transform(lambda s: s.dt.tz_localize(s.name)
                          .dt.tz_convert('America/Denver'))
                       )
```

but I get

```
0    2015-03-08 01:00:00-07:00
1    2015-03-08 01:30:00-07:00
2    2015-03-08 03:00:00-06:00
3    2015-03-08 03:30:00-06:00
4    2015-03-08 04:00:00-06:00
5    2015-03-08 01:00:00-07:00
6    2015-03-08 01:30:00-07:00
7    2015-03-08 03:00:00-06:00
8    2015-03-08 03:30:00-06:00
9    2015-11-01 00:30:00-06:00
10   2015-11-01 01:00:00-06:00
11   2015-11-01 01:30:00-06:00
12   2015-11-01 01:00:00-07:00
13   2015-11-01 01:30:00-07:00
14   2015-11-01 01:00:00-07:00
15   2015-11-01 01:30:00-07:00
16   2015-11-01 02:00:00-07:00
17   2015-11-01 02:30:00-07:00
18   2015-11-01 03:00:00-07:00
19   2015-11-01 03:30:00-07:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, America/Denver]
```

which results in non-monotonically increasing UTC time, which is obviously wrong after applying `local.dt.tz_convert('UTC')`

```
0    2015-03-08 08:00:00+00:00
1    2015-03-08 08:30:00+00:00
2    2015-03-08 09:00:00+00:00
3    2015-03-08 09:30:00+00:00
4    2015-03-08 10:00:00+00:00
5    2015-03-08 08:00:00+00:00
6    2015-03-08 08:30:00+00:00
7    2015-03-08 09:00:00+00:00
8    2015-03-08 09:30:00+00:00
9    2015-11-01 06:30:00+00:00
10   2015-11-01 07:00:00+00:00
11   2015-11-01 07:30:00+00:00
12   2015-11-01 08:00:00+00:00
13   2015-11-01 08:30:00+00:00
14   2015-11-01 08:00:00+00:00
15   2015-11-01 08:30:00+00:00
16   2015-11-01 09:00:00+00:00
17   2015-11-01 09:30:00+00:00
18   2015-11-01 10:00:00+00:00
19   2015-11-01 10:30:00+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

as the output.

If it's UTC should there be multiple instances of the times like in lines 0 and 5 of the final output? UTC is monotonically increasing, so what is going on here? Is it a problem with my input data?

Comment: why do you want to apply a manual offset instead of setting a time zone using `tz_localize` ?

Comment: Besides, your example data contains some non-existent datetimes for tz America/Denver, e.g. `2015-03-08 02:00:00`; see [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/denver?year=2015) (after 01:59 am, 3:00 am followed on that date). So I wouldn't expect monotonically increasing times in UTC if you enforce a manual offset...